# Why the results are not the same? (matrices)

Tags: equations, microsoft-excel-2019

Last image is the question and the official result

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems like a failure of your textbook. There is a difference between arrays and matrices, and Excel needs to be told that something is being treated as being a matrix rather than just an array. Your textbook should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `MMULT` function to do proper matrix multiplication when you calculate `[x, y]`:

```
=MMULT(Ainv, b)
```

otherwise instead of taking dot products, it just does pair-wise multiplication (0.10526316 * 11 = 1.15789474)

Comment: Thank you so much!